# Django List Ordering

Tags: django, filtering

I have a model called bank that has Credit class associated to a user.
Then I have a model called program that has NewProgram class associated also to a user.

Now, I would like to list out all NewProgram objects order by users Credit ascending to my views.py.
And i have no idea how am i going to do that using .order_by method.

I hope someone who could give me some hint.

Heres my code:

Appname: Bank

models.py

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    credit_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    depositor = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.depositor.username
```

Appname: Programs

```
class NewProgram(models.Model):
    program_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='program_creator')
    joining_credit_value_offer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    site = models.ForeignKey('ProgramSite')
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    referrals = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ReferredUser')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Heres what i'm trying to accomplish

```
list = NewProgram.objects.all().order_by(<Users Credit><ASC>)
```

Thanks a lot, Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this

```
list = NewProgram.objects.all().order_by('-program_creator__credit__credic_balance')
```

Django follows the relationships through `__` .

Comment: Will it work even though Credit model is not directly related to NewProgram? The only thing that relates NewProgram and Credit is by User , NewProgram has program_creator as User while Credit has program_creator as User

Comment: @DjangoBot, oh, I missed that. But that can be solved by using `-program_creator__credit__...'`, check the updated query.

Comment: Your the man Rohan, Nice Thanks a lot for helping a newbie like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this:

```
#Note, no need to use .all()
list = NewProgram.objects.filter(credit_set__depositor="some_user")
```

Comment: Did not work, Cannot resolve keyword 'credit_set' into field. Choices are: content, creation_date, desc, id, is_published, joining_credit_value_offer, program_creator, referrals, referreduser, site, title, uid